# How do I get a Canon Multipass MP390 working?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Setting up a computer for a college student. Have this Canon MultiPASS MP390 printer/scanner/copier with the Canon CD. Will not load into Ubuntu 11.10. Trying to print comes up empty. Went to Canon's web site and they have no driver for Linux for this printer.

Comment: I don't think recommending to someone to upgrade their entire OS to get the printer working is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9585597&postcount=5) the printer is recognized if you choose the s600 printer driver.

Click on the Ubuntu button and search for "Printers", then click on Add a printer, and select Canon and S600 as the model and driver. Unfortunately I don't have a new printer to add so I can't show you exactly where in the Printer tool that is.